# How to publish videos on facebook using jwplayer

Tags: facebook-opengraph, jwplayer

I am trying to embed the jwplayer video player into facebook to play the video directly in facebook for this i set the meta tags as described in this article [Publish Your Videos to Facebook with a JW Player](https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/).
but when I share the video on facebook, facebook is not playing the video, and gives the following error

"Video Formator or MIME type is not supported"

this is my test video link [Test video link](http://aghazonline.com/designjob2/living-with-invisible-diseases/)

How can I embed the jwplayer into facebook to play my videos directly.

Thanks.

Comment: the last version of JW 5 is the only Player that works with  facebook embed: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16227907-facebook-embedding